# Compiled react with browserify and babel says : ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, browserify

**Problem**: No build error, but when trying to use the file on browser, console says : `ReferenceError: React is not defined`.

Compiling react file using these two commands :

```
npx browserify \
-t [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env ] ] \
./input.jsx -o ./temp1.js
```

Then :

```
npx babel ./temp1.js \
--presets=@babel/preset-react,@babel/preset-env,minify \
--no-comments --out-file ./output.js
```

My `input.jsx` file looks like this :

```
import react from 'react';
import Testing from './component/testing.jsx'
import reactDOM from 'react-dom';

reactDOM.render
(
    <Testing></Testing>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And the `./component/testing.jsx` looks like this :

```
import React from 'react';

class Testing extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default Testing;
```

package.json / versions :

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.2.3"
}
}
```

Node : v10.9.0
NPM : 6.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a naming problem. On this import statement (input.jsx):

`import react from 'react';`

change `react` for `React`